# Read connectionstring from .ini file

Tags: c#, .net, console-application

I have a .ini file which contains a ConnectionString in the following format;

```
[system]
DatabaseDriver=ODBC;DSN=MyDb;database=MyDb;
OLEDB=Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Initial Catalog=MyDb;Data Source=PTCIMG_75x_DS;
DatabaseVersion=7.6.5
EEOApplied=Y
```

And now I need to read it from a console app, as below;

```
  var parser = new IniParser.FileIniDataParser();
  StringBuilder dbConnInt= new StringBuilder();
  string ComDBstring;

  dbConnInt = new StringBuilder();
  dbConnInt.Append("C:\\Program Files\\Database.ini"); 
  IniData dbConn = parser.LoadFile(dbConnInt.ToString());

  ComDBstring = dbConn["system"]["OLEDB"];
```

However, all I am getting, is the first part of the ConnectionString, that is `Provider=SQLOLEDB.1`. But I need the whole line, `Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Initial Catalog=MyDb;Data Source=PTCIMG_75x_DS;`. Why is it being delimited by the `;` and returning only the first part?

Any idea from anyone?

Many thanks in anticipation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because according to the documentation, [`;` and onward is interpreted as a comment](https://code.google.com/p/ini-parser/wiki/Usage).

You can change the comment delimiter to `#` for example:

```
// Change character used as comment delimiter (defaults to ';')
parser.CommentDelimiter = '#';
```